# Why do we need isogonal trajectories?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Could you, please, give me some examples, where we really need isogonal, but not orthogonal, trajectories? I know, how to find them using differential equations. I would like to see some examples in physics or engineering or somewhere else. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The rhumb lines are isogonal lines and they had a role in geography and nautics. Too, think of a parametrization of some surface for wich the coordinate curves aren't orthogonal (you'll be able to find some examples from this site if you search the obvious terms and employ some patience).

Comment: @rafa-budría Rhumb lines - it's great idea, I like it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome :)